# SnowFlake using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am working on a new Project and requirement of the project is to design an API endpoint that connects with Snowflake using .NET Core

I found a solution that we can connect to SnowFlake using this [LINK](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/). This approach looks like a traditional way to connect to any data source.

But I want to use Entity Framework Core to connect with SnowFlake?

Please help me with this issue?
If possible any Sample application/sample code to connect with a SnowFlake using EF Core

Comment: I found this link on the Snowflake Community board.  Maybe it has some useful information for you, although its a year old.  https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00009Gx5ZVSAZ/how-to-use-snowflake-in-entity-framework-core

Comment: That link was not clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can see a few sample apps [here](http://cdn.cdata.com/help/OWE/ado/pg_usingEFCoreIntro.htm) but they use the CData ASP.NET driver which is insanely expensive.

Comment: crazy expensive.